# mtry tuning given by caret higher than the number of predictors

Tags: r, feature-selection, random-forest, caret

According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25763977/1100107), it seems that the `train` function of the `caret` package returns a `mtry` parameter of `randomForest` possibly higher than the number of predictor variables, because it expands the `X` data into a matrix with dummy variables and considers the columns of this matrix. However a value of the `mtry` parameter highest than `ncol(X)` is not valid in the `randomForest` function. Therefore I'm lost here : what should we do in such a case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `train` with the matrix argument, i.e.

```
tr1 <- train(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris) # gives mtry = 5, not allowed
# but change to
tr2 <- train(iris[, -1], iris[, 1]) # gives mtry = 3
```

I think `train` creates the model matrix and then passes it to `randomForest` when using the formula argument, thus considering every column of that matrix a separate variable. This does not seem to happen when using the matrix argument.

I am not entirely up to speed on the inner workings of `train` but from what I have read this seems to be the case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was puzzling because I use the `formula` in `randomForest` and this does not creates the model matrix.

Comment: From what I can understand of the source code for `train.formula`, it creates the model matrix from the formula, expanding factor variables into dummy variables and dropping the intercept for further use by `train` with its matrix argument. There may be some other things going on as well but that seems to be where the issue is at.

Comment: Yes, stupid (or lazy) of me for not having look at the code.